# Is it possible to run a NGINX server alongside with Pi-hole on a Raspberry Pi 1 B?

Tags: raspbian, web-server, pi-1, pi-hole, nginx

I already have Pi-hole 5.0 and PiVPN installed. I plan to install an NGINX server to serve one PHP script for personal use.

Here's the example script:

```
//voicefax2text.php on myserver.com
<?php
$fromstr = $_REQUEST['From'];
$recordingurlstr = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; // for vm
$mediaurlstr = $_REQUEST['MediaUrl']; // for fax
$sms= "\"Body=Signalwire: ".$fromstr." ".$recordingurlstr." ".$mediaurlstr."\"";

exec ("curl https://[yourname].signalwire.com/api/laml/2010-04-01/Accounts/[yourProjectID]/Messages.json -X POST --data-urlencode \"From=+14161231234\" --data-urlencode {$sms} --data-urlencode \"To=+14169876543\" -u \"[yourProjectID]:[yourToken]\"");

?>
```

Can my Pi 1B handle it?
If so, is there a guide that I can follow so I don't mess this up? Lol

Answer (score 2):

Unless it’s changed you can run PI-Hole itself on NGINX  but any updates had a habit of defaulting back to lighttpd for the browser.

There are a set of instructions (unofficial as of June 2020) [here](https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/nginx-configuration/) to configure the default site.  Because of this you may need to look at how you run your script
under a different site / IP address not used by pi-hole.

I would look at getting your software to run under lightttpd TBH as it will help to keep future issues to a minimum :)

Note theoretically you should be able to run both servers at the same time as long as php versions and port usage does not clash BUT it’s not something I would do...

Comment: Would you suggest that I do something like this?
https://rafaelc.org/tech/p/running-a-web-server-while-using-pi-hole/

Comment: Think it’s a bit overkill - just create your site to work on a different port (e.g. 8080) if it runs under lighttpd.